# What is the best way to build a website-based Android shell app?

Tags: android, shell, video-streaming, image

Topic: What is the best way to build a website-based Android shell app for a website like YouTube? And what are the limitations or disadvantages?

We have a website, which allows users upload and view videos & pictures. Now we are planning on building a Android shell app. The basic functions are to view video & picture, take video & picture and upload video & picture.

Can you please suggest us a good way or any funny way to develop this kind of app fast?

Thanks

Comment: What's a "website-based Android shell app"?

Comment: I believe he means a native Android app that interfaces with a web service through an API.

Comment: I mean an Android webapp that can show website contents, and can upload contents to the website. I have found a few articles talking about Webview. But it seems to have no camera support.